# php multiplication of two cell input by user

Tags: php

```
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) 
{
print("<tr>");
print("<td>$i</td>");

print("<td><input type='text' name='meter[$i]' class='meter' maxlength='21' id='meter[$i]' /></td>");
                    print("<td><input type='text' name='weight[$i]' maxlength='21' class='weight' id='weight[$i]' size='10' /></td>");
print("<td><input type='text' name='amount[$i]' maxlength='21' class='amount' id='amount[$i]' size='10' /></td>");                  
print("</tr>");
}
?>
```

i want like this

if i enter 110 in meter and 10 in weight it should give me ans (10/110)*100;
in each column

```
(weight/meter)*100
```

```
  meter  weight  output
    110   | 10   |  9.09
    120   | 12   |  10
    130   | 14   |  10.76
```

Comment: Are you planning to post the form and have it refresh with the data populated or do you want to do all of the calculation in the client with javascript and without submitting the page?

Comment: You cannot fill and evaluate the form at the same time using php as server side scripting language while the form is used on the client side. That is obvious once you think of it that way. So either you have to use client side logic, that would be javascript instead of php, or you need to keep for and result separate and have a request to the server between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by using a javascript code, so that the calculation is done locally in the browser's client, without the need to submit a form to the server:

```
<?php
print("<script>");
print("function calculate(index) {;");
print("     var meterd = document.getElementById('meter['+index+']');");
print("     var weightd = document.getElementById('weight['+index+']');");
print("     var amountd = document.getElementById('amount['+index+']');");
print("     if (meterd && weightd && amountd) {;");
print("         var meter = parseFloat(meterd.value); if (isNaN(meter)) {meter = 1;}");
print("         var weight = parseFloat(weightd.value); if (isNaN(weight)) {weight = 0;}");
print("         amountd.value = weight * 100 / meter;");
print("     };");
print("};");
print("</script>");

print("<table>");
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) 
{
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td>$i</td>");
    print("<td><input type='text' name='meter[$i]' class='meter' maxlength='21' id='meter[$i]' onkeyup='calculate($i)'/></td>");
    print("<td><input type='text' name='weight[$i]' maxlength='21' class='weight' id='weight[$i]' size='10' onkeyup='calculate($i)'/></td>");
    print("<td><input type='text' name='amount[$i]' maxlength='21' class='amount' id='amount[$i]' size='10' /></td>");                  
    print("</tr>");
}
print("</table>");
?>
```

Tested, it worked for me.

Comment: it work only i have to change amountd.value = (weight  / meter)*100;  i want to display only 2 digit after decimal eg : 9.22  not 9.22223456

Answer (score 0):

To have only 2 decimals, you can use javascript value1.toFixed(2):

```
print("         var value1 = weight * 100 / meter;");
print("         amountd.value = value1.toFixed(2);");
```